# Check ContentEditable content

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

What is the way to control input user (forbidden words, in instance) in ContentEditable field (Html 5) with jQuery?

```
<div contentEditable="true" id="title" >
...
$('#title').focus(function()
...
```

doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Vincent

Comment: This could help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391278/contenteditable-change-events
Or this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745644/event-capturing-vs-bubbling-with-a-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 4):

If you want to control the user's input, you should be handling the `keydown` event, or something along those lines. In that event handler, if the user enters a forbidden key, you can do `e.preventDefault()` so that the key is not entered in the element. For eg.

```
$('div[contenteditable=true]').keydown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @Tim. + 1. Thanks. I think it's too complex for me! :)

Comment: `contenteditable=""` or `contenteditable="true"` Indicates that the element is editable. [Source](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) So you would also have to check for `contenteditable=""`